# @using(Html.BeginForm) inside @if

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to use a view-based authorization and when i do the following, i get Server error in the application

```
        @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
        {

            <h4>Create a new document</h4>
            @using(Html.BeginForm("Create", "Document", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                <span>SOME HTML COD</span>
            }
        }
        else
        { <span>Vous devez être administrateur pour accéder à cette section</span>}
    }
    else
    {<span>Vous devez être connecté pour accéder à cette section</span>}
```

What may be the solution or the problem ?

[THE ERROR CAPTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVJp5.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove @ from using (Html.BeginForm... there is not required @, @ only required if any condition in div tag

```
    @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
    {

        <h4>Create a new document</h4>
            using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Document", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                <span>SOME HTML COD</span>
            }
    }
    else
    { <span>Vous devez être administrateur pour accéder à cette section</span>}
}
else
{<span>Vous devez être connecté pour accéder à cette section</span>}
```

Comment: And for @Html.AntiForgeryToken() ? Do we need to remove the @ ?

Comment: not for @Html.AntiForgeryToken()  keep @. working or not